# My Code push is failing due to git Targetting the another git account user name

Tags: java, git, github, gitlab, git-bash

Thanks for reviewing my question. i'm facing issue with my git push. i have 2 github accounts, i'm accessing the 2nd account through git bash but when i'm trying to push the code in to github it is denied the request due to push request going from other account user name.. i updated the global username,email and Credential username but still i'm getting the same 403 response. please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: GitBash commandline screen print]

Comment: Try opening your .gitconfig manually and replacing all occurrences of the other account with the one you want

Comment: can you please explain how can i do that.. i'm new to git

Comment: i opened the gitconfig file and i able to see my new details only

Comment: GitHub looks at your ssh key to identify you.

Comment: so what i have to do for that

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute `git config --list` to check current username & email in your local repository.
2. Change your username & email as desired. Set it globally or specific to the local repository:

   `git config [--global] user.name "Username"`

   `git config [--global] user.email "Email@Adress.com"`
3. You could also edit .git/config manually instead to your desired username.
4. Alternatively, if you push over https protocol, Github will prompt for username/password each time you push.
5. You can just switch to https, rather than ssh. If you use https, it will respect the .git/config settings. So, in .git/config, change:

   `url = git@github.com:USER/PROJECT.git`

   to

   `url = https://USER@github.com/USER/PROJECT.git`

   or via terminal

   `git remote set-url origin "Remoteurl"`
6. Github identifies you by the ssh key.

   Use `ssh-add -l` to determine which keys you are using, and `ssh-add -d <keyfile>` to remove a specific key, if it dosent work remove the 'unwanted' ssh key from ~/.ssh/config

Comment: i dont know whether i'm seeing the correct file or not but i'm able to see only username and email..other than that there is nothing to edit

Answer (score 0):

i deleted my credentials stored in the windows credentials manager.. and it resolved my problem